# BreezeJS failure callback causing a 'undefined is not an object error' exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

The following breeze query works perfectly fine

```
var manager = emFactory.newManager();
return manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded);
```

but when i add the failure callback and re-run the application

```
var manager = emFactory.newManager();
return manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(function (err) {});
```

an ***'undefined is not an object error'*** exception it thrown.

I've been scratching my head on this one for a while so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you have the function querySucceeded?

Comment: function querySucceeded(data) {
      sensors = data.results;
      log("Retrieved Sensors from server", sensors.length, true);
                return sensors;
    };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I got it.

It's not `fail` it's `catch`.

use it like this:

```
return manager.executeQuery(q).then(success).catch(failed);
```

edit: with

```
function success(response) {}
```

and

```
function failed(error) {}
```

Comment: Check out the promises sample from the official docs http://www.breezejs.com/sites/default/files/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_executeQuery could it be the docs are incorrect?

Comment: It seems so. Maybe that's something old and should be corrected. Is it possible to do that there?

Comment: eventually, this `catch` comes from the $q promise in angular and the `fail` comes from the Q.js promise? -> [breeze angular documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-angular-service)

Comment: Yes, that explains it, $q.then takes multiple parameters where as the then from Q.js takes a single callback and returns a promise.

Comment: Just noticed this too... catch works but fail does not